# Установка драйверов в windows

Tags: windows, installshield

Столкнулся с проблемой при установке драйвера в Windows 7. Пытаюсь установить драйвер, который сам написал. Установка завершается некорректно. Она падает на регистрации в реестре, пишет, что невозможно добавить ключ. Отдельно проверял все этапы установки. Я бы хотел узнать, можно ли и как получить нечто, вроде лога установки? Если кто знает, может есть другие способы посмотреть, что твориться в установщике?

Answer (score 3):

Windows при установке драйверов ведет лог. Этот лог возможно посмотреть после окончания установки. Он хранится в `%WINDIR%\inf\setupapi.dev`

Comment: прошу прощения но это тавтология: "PathToWindowsDir\windows\".
Пишите либо %systemdrive%\windows\..., либо %windir%\...

Comment: (исправил)